# how to implement unpackWARs tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, war, unpack

Kind of a noob with tomcat 7, how do you implement this setting found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes

Trying to set unpackWARs to true so i dont have to manually unpack a war to deploy it, but have no idea where to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting can be found in *server.xml* under your Tomcat 7 configuration directory.  For example, on Ubuntu, this is */etc/tomcat7/server.xml*, and the setting is part of the `<Host>` element:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```